# Cannot find <stdio.h> on Heroku

Tags: python, c, heroku

I am trying to host an online judge backend on Heroku. The endpoint accepts code and test cases, compiles the code, tests it, and returns results of the test cases. Everything works fine on my local Linux.
When I deploy it to Heroku, it works well for Python but while compiling C, it shows this error:

> 2020-07-19T14:45:14.342402+00:00 app[web.1]: app/static/Code/test1.c:1:10: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory

I am quite new to Heroku. I've added Python build pack. I tried adding C build pack as well from this link: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-c.git. Still it is showing the same error.

Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I guess Heroku Python dynos aren't set up for compiling C. You could probably make a docker image to deploy to Heroku instead of using dynos, set up with all the compilers you need?

Comment: Thank you so much @Rup
Deploying Docker image to Heroku worked fine. :)